# Slow select queries when cron update tables in the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem with the shop based on woocommerce. Shop update his stocks and price every hour (around 500 products per minute) in the background (Cron) and during this update process, select queries slows down (TTFB increase from 300ms to 1900ms).

I use MySQL with InnoDB engine on dedicated server (4 core xeon + 16GB ram).

My question is, what can I do to increase select queries speed during the update?

Maybe should I use one big update query instead lots of single ones for every product? or there is other solution to tune mysql server in this case?

Thx for help,
Marcin

Comment: Have you checked whether your `SELECT` queries can be optimized through indices? Or is the webserver itself under high load and the MySQL server is not the bottleneck? You could try to offload the update process to another server (like having a webserver for the customers and a "maintanance server" doing all background work)

Comment: @Nico Haase, yes I optimized indicates and shop works great when it not update anything in the background. I will think about temporary tables for updates only. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is expected if your table size is big enough to choke MySql while updates are going on. While updating a lot of records in MySql will reindex the updated tuples. 

 Through **InnoDb** takes row level locks, but if the select needs to use any index which is in rebuilding process. It might cause some trouble.

 One thing you could do is a SELECT on a single row if your query allows. And update in huge batches rather than continuously.

Switch on *SLOW_QUERY_LOGGING*, and observe that your slow queries are because of lock wait or index not being used. This will help you narrow down your problem

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, I will try to updates products with huge batches, maybe this will solve the problem. Thanks again.